# Is there a way to get the Number of reads and writes as per documents

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get the number of reads and writes a user is using while on the app.

I am using Firestore and I have a collection named users and that collection has a list of users. I want to get the number of reads and writes a user is making so I can charge the user accordingly. Is there any way to find that?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the number of reads and writes a user is using while on the app.

You can count the number of document reads, but there is nothing built-in, you have to write code for that. So you can [increment](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value) a counter each time a user reads a document.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. If we are calculating number of reads as you mentioned this would increase the number of writes also because it has to be stored somewhere in real time which will increase the cost. Is there any cost efficient way to deploy the application individually so I can get the number of read/writes for a particular collection created for a user. Note: We are creating a whole work history of  User which would include analytics, data being stored in realtime of location and Task and project.

Comment: You can store the counter in the [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database). There is no cost for the write operation while reading a counter will cost you an incredibly small amount of money.

Comment: Hey Sadil. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?